# Scapy library modifies the method map()

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, scapy

I use the mapp method to go from list(str) to list(int), but when I call the scapy library. I do not get the same result.

I use python 2.7.13

```
print "E: {}".format(map(int, ['1', '2']))
```

return

```
E: [1, 2]
```

and

```
from scapy.all import *
print "E: {}".format(map(int, ['1', '2']))
```

return

```
E: <itertools.imap object at 0x0405E730
```

Comment: I tried your code with _python 2.7.13_ and worked fine for me... are you sure `scapy` causes the issue ?

Comment: Yes. The code works for me on Linux but not on windows.
Did you try with windows?

Comment: Scapy seems to be using itertools.imap instead of map. Do no use star import, do something like `from scapy import all as s`

Comment: no, I tried this code on mac os...

Answer (score 2):

That's the risk you have when you import a module into your namespace in Python.

Here, you're using a development version of Scapy and that's a bug (you should not import Scapy's `map()`, which is the one provided by the `six` module, when importing Scapy). You should probably [report it](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/new).

However, to avoid this, you should import Scapy in its own namespace. For example:

```
from scapy import all as scapy
scapy.IP() / scapy.ICMP()  # this will work
print "E: {}".format(map(int, ['1', '2']))  # this will display a list
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I will do